# PHP: Как можно полученные подстроки дальше преобразовать в массив?

Tags: php, strtok

```
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
        /* В качестве разделителей используем пробел, табуляцию и перевод строки */
        $tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");          
        while ($tok !== false) {
            echo "Word=$tok<br />";
            $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего кода вот так

```php
$res = [];
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
/* В качестве разделителей используем пробел, табуляцию и перевод строки */
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");          
while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $res[] = $tok;
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
var_dump($tok);
```

А вообще вот так

```php
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
$res = mb_split("[ \n\t]+", $string);
```

Где `[ \n\t]` - это регулярное выражение, которое говорит, что разбиваем по одному из символов , `\n`, `\t`, а `+` говорит о том, что таких символов может стоять рядом один или больше

Comment: А второе что-то и не работает.

Comment: @u_mulder. Логично. Поправил.

Comment: Буду занудой до конца и скажу что `[ \n\t]+` чтобы разбивать по всяким `\n\n\t` или `\n \n`.

Comment: @u_mulder принимается

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, Вы можете воспользоваться несколькими методами

Чтобы просто добавить полученные строки в массив - используйте `array_push`
Пример вместе со словом `word=`:

```php
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
/* В качестве разделителей используем пробел, табуляцию и перевод строки */
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");
$Arr = array();
while ($tok !== false) {
    $bz = "Word=$tok";
    array_push($Arr, $bz);
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
print_r($Arr);
```

Соответственно без слова `word`:

```php
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
/* В качестве разделителей используем пробел, табуляцию и перевод строки */
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");
$Arr = array();
while ($tok !== false) {
    array_push($Arr, $tok);
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
print_r($Arr);
```

Либо заменить сначала в строке табуляцию и перенос строки, а потом разбить на массив:

```php
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
$bz = str_replace( "\t", ' ', $string);
$bz = str_replace( "\n", ' ', $bz);
$tok = explode( ' ', $bz);

print_r($tok);
```